# How to display JSON's structure in IntelliJ?

Tags: json

For example, for a simple file like this, it displays everything in one line:

```
{"315": "appear", "1529": "perVobj", "88": "JJR", "2212": "xM"}
```

I would like it to be displayed at multiple lines, like:

```
{
  key:value,
  key: value,
  ...
}
```

Comment: you can do using https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3964-json-formatter

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

**Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L**

it would reformat your file

Answer (score 1):

go to `File->Settings->Code Style->JSON` and set as per your needs.
[image]

---

Further, go to settings and create shortcut for reformat or use Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L(default) to reformat the file.
see this[image]